# Does using a read committed isolation level and a NOLOCK query hint impact performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isolation-level, hints

Can having both the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` and `WITH (NOLOCK)` on all tables in SP cause conflicts and downgrade performance on the SP?  I just noticed some changes that a dev made in the SP recently.

Comment: Regardless of the more or less semantic question here, if you have `NOLOCK` littered throughout your queries, [please give this a good read](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Answer (score 4):

If you have stored procedure that starts with:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

And then you have a `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable mt WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Then the `SELECT` query will use the READ **UNCOMMITED** isolation level* - in other words, the NOLOCK will override the SET statement.  This is documented in [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

> All read operations performed within the transaction operate under the rules for the specified isolation level unless a table hint in the FROM clause of a statement specifies different locking or versioning behavior for a table.

As far as performance, using `NOLOCK` will ignore locks taken by other queries, and take / release locks more quickly, so you will likely experience less blocking.  However, this is at the expense of the *correctness* of the results.

** Since this is a table-level hint, the hint would need to be applied to each table involved in the SELECT query in order to be functionally equivalent to using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED*

Comment: "I got the wrong answer, **real fast**!"